# Detect if a language is translated or not

Tags: localization, conditional

For entries where the content isn't translated yet I'd like to add a "Sorry not translated yet" message.

Since all the content is synced is there a way to check if the synced content is the same as in the other locales?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try adding something like the following to the end of your template. This is assuming you only have 2 locales.

```
{# test for the current entry locale (i.e. spanish) #}
{% if entry.locale = 'es' %}

    {# retrieve the same entry in the original locale #}
    {% set localizedEntry = craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale('en') %}

    {# compare the body content, and append additional content #}
    {% if localizedEntry[0].body == entry.body %}
        Sorry, not translated yet.
    {% endif %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Cool. Could you explain what is exactly happening here? What does `[0]` do?

Comment: `craft.entries` returns an ElementCriteriaModel that essentially acts like an array of entries, even if it only has 1 entry. `[0]` or `.first` returns the first item in the array.

Comment: In this case, you could also use: `{% set localizedEntry = craft.entries.id(entry.id).locale('en').first %}` and then wouldn't need the `[0]` in the `if` statement.