# Check which locales of an Entry are active

Tags: plugin-development

I have a section called News with 2 locales: 'en' and 'nl'. For some News items I have both languages switched on and for some only 1 language. The screenshot shows an example of an entry with only 1 language switched on.

[image]

Is there a php method to check the Entry object which languages are switch on?

Comment: Possible duplicate? See http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/2991/detect-if-a-language-is-translated-or-not

Comment: The link to the other question could be a solution but doesn't seem to be a very neat one. At the moment I can get the enabled locales from a hook in the CMS section like this: ```craft()->templates->hook('cp.entries.edit.right-pane', function(&$context) {
$locales = $context['enabledLocales']}```
Is there another way to get these enabledLocales straight from an entry object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a quick search through the Craft app folder I found this method:

```
craft()->elements->getEnabledLocalesForElement($variables['entry']->id)
```

You can probably use this and send the EntryModel's id as the parameter

Comment: That worked perfectly well! Thank @Joris!

Answer (score 1):

Needed this for Craft 3 and came up with the following solution. Not sure if it’s the best approach, but it works.

```
/**
 * Returns in which sites an entry has active content
 * @entryId {int}
 * @return {array}
 */
public function getEntryLocales($entryId)
{
    $supportedSites = Entry::find()->id($entryId)->one()->getSupportedSites();
    $locales = array();

    foreach ($supportedSites as $site) {
        $entry = Entry::find()->id($entryId)->siteId($site['siteId'])->one();

        if ($entry) {
            $locales[] = $entry->site->language;
        }
    }

    return $locales;
}
```